# Refreshing an iframe which are in different domains

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, iframe

I have a page called `main.jsp` which is in domain `domain1` and it has a iframe which loads contents from `domain2`. Basically `main.jsp` is a common contents and in iframe we load contents from other web applications deployed on different servers.

My problem is I want to refresh the content inside iframe automatically (say 5 seconds). I tried this code first:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<s:url includeParams="all" />" />
```

`Err: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame`

I tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload() }, 15000);
</script>
```

Which also gives me same error. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Note:
I have added this code to get rid of cross-domain issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.domain = window.location.hostname.replace('www.', '');
</script>
```

Comment: Just set the source of the iframe in the parent page 
`iframe.src = iframe.src;`

Comment: put that meta only inside the iframes `main.jsp`

Comment: @Sarath main.jsp contains common functionality used across the applications, so I need to refresh only in one page of on of the application.

Comment: try to add it dynamicaly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it dynamicaly

```
   function addRefresh(){
       var meta = document.createElement('meta');
       meta.setAttribute("http-equiv", "refresh");
       meta.setAttribute("content", "5");
       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
    }

    if(location.origin === 'domain1.com'){
      addRefresh();
    }
```

Comment: So when I frame loads, the main page will also loads? Because when I click button on main page, the content of iframe (where refresh needs to happen) gets displayed. I think by that time main frame already will be loaded right?

Comment: the meta will add only inside iframe of `domain1` .. rest of pages will not have the meta itself

Comment: @PradeepSimha is it loading the whole page ?

Comment: no, main page just contains navigational links etc. So user clicks some link there and page from different application loads on iframe.

Comment: so you don't have control on the content loading inside iframe?

Comment: I have control inside iframe but don't have control on main.jsp